# Overlapping Mined Conversations

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, data-mining, sentiment-analysis

I'm playing around with the [twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet) and am trying to extract conversations. The dataframe "trying" is sorted from most recent tweet to latest tweet. Now I want to go through the dataframe and mine for the conversation. This entails that I want to go from the end of the conversation to the beginning of the conversation. The beginning of a conversation is defined if the "in_reply_to_status_id_str" is a null value. I am able to successfully extract the conversations but the issue I am running into is that a conversation that is longer than 2 will have subsets.

So for example a conversation that is defined as [10, 4, 5, 6] but then [4, 5, 6] and [5, 6] are defined as conversations even though they are just subsets of the bigger conversation. So the goal is to get rid of these subsets and just keep the the big conversation.  Here is another example: [100, 50, 30] is defined as a conversation correctly, then later in the running of the code [50,30] is defined as a conversation (is a subset do not want this). There are cases in which [60,30] is a  correctly defined conversation so I can't just delete the rows once a conversation has been defined correctly as there these instances in which 2 users are replying to "30".
You will find a further examples at the bottom of my code.

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=str)
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'])
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['created_at'], ascending=False)
trying = df_sorted.copy()

'''Will take a bit above 3 hours to run

Trying to get conversation from most recent to start of conversation. Beginning of Conversation
is defined when "in_reply_to_status_id_str" is a null value.

Take for example row1: has reply_status = 9 and id_str = 10
find row in which the reply_status of row1 is equal to this row's id_str. 
Continue this process until reply_status is equal to null (have found start)'''

for index, row in trying.iterrows():
    single_convo = []
    
    response_var = row['in_reply_to_status_id_str']
    
    if pd.notnull(trying.loc[index, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str']):
        single_convo.append([index, row['user_id_str'], row['id_str']])
        
    cont = True #checks if you need to continue checking for whole conversation 
    
    while cont:
        for index2, row2 in trying.iterrows():
            if response_var == row2['id_str']:
                single_convo.append([index2, row2['user_id_str'], row2['id_str']])
                if pd.isnull(trying.loc[index2, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str']):
                    single_convo.append('start of convo found')
                    display(single_convo)
                    cont = False 
                    break
                else:
                    response_var = row2['in_reply_to_status_id_str']
            if len(trying[trying['id_str'] == response_var]) == 0:
                cont = False
                break
                
    if len(single_convo) > 0: #single convo will be empty when row['in_reply_to_status_id_str'] = NaN
        conversations.append(single_convo)
    
display(conversations)

print("My program took", (time.time() - start_time)/60, "minutes to run")


'''[3493, 3491, 3487, 3473] next one is [3491, 3487, 3473], will create another for [3487, 3473] 
only want to keep longest one 

there will be instances when: 

[[1365, '1.1450879244148859e+18'],
 [1361, '1.1450866432647905e+18'],
 [1353, '1.1450837341458719e+18']
 ['start of convo found']],
 
.... (subset does not always appear right after)

[[1361, '1.1450866432647905e+18'], 
[1353, '1.1450837341458719e+18'],
['start of convo found']] (don't want)

[[1360, '1.1450864696206049e+18'],
[1353, '1.1450837341458719e+18'],
['start of convo found']] (want to keep)
'''
```